# DPMM asymptotics for finite mixtures?

Tags: bayesian, asymptotics, dirichlet-process, nonparametric-bayes, finite-mixture-model

My understanding is that using a Dirichlet process mixture model for a mixture with finitely many components will result in a misspecified model. Are there any asymptotic results or bounds on the misspecification error? I'm particularly curious about the case where $N << K$, i.e. the number of data points are far fewer than the number of clusters. Will a DPMM still be a suitable technique for inference?

Comment: How is it possible to have N<<K? K is not fixed in DP and can grow as data arrives, but it never exceeds the number of data points N.

Comment: Sure, but I was wondering about (frequentist) risk estimates when there are $K$ true clusters, but you only have $N$ data points. Will the DPMM correctly cluster?

Comment: Well, that's the idea: to have a flexible model that adjust its complexity as data arrives. In this sense, DP will always result in $K\leq N$.